# Solution verification: $A\sim B\implies \mathscr P(A)\sim \mathscr P(B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove that if $A$~$B$ then $\mathscr{P}(A)$~$\mathscr{P}(B)$, where ~ shows equivalence between sets.

Proof: Since $A$~$B$ we define a function $f:A\to B$ such that f is one-to-one and onto by the formula $f(a)=a+1$. Define  $g:\mathscr{P}(A)\to\mathscr{P}(B)$ for arbitrary $k,n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $n=|A|$,

$g(\{a_1,...,a_k\})= 
\begin{cases} \{a_1 +1,...,a_k+1\}, &\text{$1\le k\le 2^{n-1}$}\\
\{a_k+1\}, &\text{$n=1$}\\
\end{cases}$

It's easy to check that $g$ is one-to-one and onto.

Comment: What if $A$ and $B$ aren't sets of integers, real numbers or anything concrete? You also seem to be assuming $A$ and $B$ are finite. What exactly are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Then $f$ is taken as a succesion function that takes an element and produces the one next to it

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, but while you're at it, how do you even know such a function $f$ exists? From $A\sim B$ you can only conclude that there exists a bijeciton between $A$ and $B$. You don't know how it behaves.

Comment: Could you use the axiom of choice to assume it does??

Comment: No. If $A=B=\{1\}$, then $f(1)=2\not \in B$ making it ill-defined.

Comment: So i can only use this proof if i know what $A$ and $B$ are??

Comment: Not even then, as I've illustrated. Also look at my first comment.

Comment: So  what you're saying is that i can only assume a bijection not a formula

Comment: That's not what I'm saying, but that is true.

Comment: In regards to a "succession function," what if one of your sets is $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{Q}$? What's the real number next to, say, 1?

Comment: @NickD i was obviously wrong in assuming a formula for the bijection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is wrong, and has several key problems.

1. Nowhere it says that $A$ and $B$ are finite sets of integers, they might be infinite sets which contain nothing that resembles integers at all.
2. The function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is **given**, and it is not defined by you.
3. More to the previous point, functions are not necessarily given by a formula, it's not the early 19th century anymore. Functions are sets of ordered pairs with certain properties.
4. Even more to the last two points, assuming that $f(a)=a+1$ seems to be an awfully specific formula, so given $A$, $B$ is uniquely determined by that function.
5. "It's easy to check that $g$ is a bijection", that right there is -50% of the grade, had I been grading that problem. This check is exactly what you are asked to prove. It is true that it is easy to check, and if you were a Ph.D. student and the course was on a much harder topic, I would have overlooked that. But this sort of problem, including your "proof" indicate that you are *far* from the point where **you** should overlook that part of the proof.

Finally, the definition of $g$, is fairly correct. You need to adjust it to the general and arbitrary case. Let me give you a hint, then.

> **HINT:** If $X\subseteq A$ then $\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: So i should assume that $f:A\to B$ is a bijection, assume that a bijection $g$ exists such that $X\subseteq A$, then $X\in \mathscr{P}(A)$ and since $\{f(x)|x\in X\} \subseteq B$, then its an element of $\mathscr{P}(B)$